# Apache: Multiple Virtual Hosts on REMOTE server

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I have a remote server with IP address **10.72.254.248**, I want to set up multiple virtual hosts on this server by giving different ports for each virtual host.

my httpd.conf:

```
Listen 80
Listen 3333

NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:3333

<VirtualHost *:80> 
     DocumentRoot "/path/to/site1/" 
     ServerName *:80
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:3333> 
     DocumentRoot "/path/to/site2/" 
     ServerName *:3333
</VirtualHost>
```

If no port specified, it will hit site1 (port 80)
When I go to **10.72.254.248** or **10.72.254.248:80** it opens site1 successfully

But when I try **10.72.254.248:3333** it doesn't work.

Is the issue to do with the syntax? or maybe with /etc/hosts file? or firewall?

Please help

**EDIT:**

When I try to connect to **10.72.254.248:3333**, I get the following error message:

`Can't connect to server 10.72.254.248:3333`

Comment: 'doesn't work' - hangs, gives an error, gets a page but 404, permission denied?  What kind of 'doesn't work'.

Comment: (1) Don't use non-standard ports unless you have a good reason (You have not provided a good reason in your question, therefore you should not be using a non-standard port. Expect strict firewalls to stomp on random high-numbered ports.).  (2) See what EightBitTony said above :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check netstat -an and make sure Apache is listening on port 3333.  Check nothing else is listening instead.  If it is, it's most likely a firewall issue (iptables -L and look for a rule allowing port 3333).

Comment: I've edited the question, it gives me an error "Can't connect to server 10.72.254.248:3333". When I tried stopping iptables firewall service "service iptables stop", it worked! Now, of course, I don't want to stop the firewall, I only want to allow that specific 3333 port, how can I do that, please?

Comment: the answer to that is both simple, and complex - simple, you need to add a rule allowing traffic on port 3333.  Complex - how you add that rule depends entirely on what you use to build your current set of firewall rules.  It's probably a single iptables command, but integrating it into your firewall requires knowing what firewall you use (its iptables based, but what product manages it for you, if anything).

Answer (score 4):

At first: "It doesn't work" is no propper error description. What do you expect to see? What do you actually observe?

Having said that, it seems you are mixing up the concepts of name based virtual hosting and IP/Port based virtual hosting. In the first case (where you actually need the `NameVirtualHost` and `ServerName` directive, you can have multiple virtual hosts on the same IP/port. Apache decides which one to use by comparing the contents of the Host header sent with each request by the client with value of the `ServerName` of the virtual host.

In your case, where you have a single vhost on a port, this is not necessary. Thus, you should remove the `NameVirtualHost` directives and the `ServerName` directives (which are in the wrong format nevertheless).

Read http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html for more information about the concept of name-based virtual hosting.

Comment: As you said, seems like I mixed between Name-base and IP-base, thanks for the info